# Stretch half an image to fit in a div and half overflow in mobile and half image display in half portion of div in desktop?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display only half of the image in a `div` and half overflow in desktop view while in mobile view image stretch and cover the full width of div without affecting half overflow part, please checkout my layout below. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with any research you have found and any attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself. What would be especially helpful is the HTML structure you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you needed, though you should probably show us some code to see what are you really trying to do.

You can check the code I did here: https://jsfiddle.net/joligoms/vx3de19L/

And the full view over here: https://jsfiddle.net/joligoms/vx3de19L/show

But let's go to the explanation (I guess :P)

So, for the HTML structure I have used:

```
<div class-"container">
  <div class="paragraph"> <!-- With some text here --> </div>
  <div class="image"> <!-- Image goes here --> </div>
</div>
```

Now on the CSS, I have used `display: flex` on the container.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

And to make the image display only half of it inside the image div, you need to set the position to `relative` and the left to `50%` just as the code below:

```
.image img {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%; /*Make sure the image occupies whole parent div's width*/
  height: 100%; /* Sets the height to parent div's size */
}
```

To change the order and make the contents inside of the container more responsive, I added a media query like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  .container div {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  
  .image {
    width: 100%; /* This is important to make the div occupy the whole container and have the image overflow you want */
    order: 1; /* Image now goes first */
  }
  
  .paragraph {
    order: 2; /* Paragraph now goes below*/
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, it's perfect, but i want the image to cover full width of `div` in mobile view also only half part of image cover full width of div.